# how to call navigationControllerPreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

i m new to ios app development.i m currently learning to work with navigation controller.Can anyone plz explain how to call -(UIInterfaceOrientation)navigationControllerPreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: have implemented it in my code ,but it is not executing at all.

thankz in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't call it, it's a delegate method that will be called by the navigation controller. You need to make whatever class you have the implementation of that method in, the delegate of the navigation controller.

Comment: thankz for ur reply.Actually i m not calling it.my problem is that it is not executed after implementing it in the class which is the delegate of navigation controller

Comment: @user3594778, I can't get that one to be called either. I tried presenting a navigation controller modally, and implemented the delegate method in the presenting view controller, but it was not called. Another delegate method, navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:, was called so I know my delegate was set properly.

Comment: @user3594778, I don't know. There's either a bug in the system, or there's some undocumented thing you need to do to get it to work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, and I've implemented it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The first method you mention is just a method which is called by the framework (if necessary) to get the "preferred Interface Orientation". For the system use this method you have to set more than one accepted interface orientation in your project setting and plist file.

The second method ´navigationController´ is inherited from ´UIViewController´ and gives a reference to the UINavigationController in which the UIViewController is embedded (means if there is no NavigationController it's nil). So it's a getter.

Now I think some more clarification in what you want to do with these methods would be useful, I mean you must have a reason why you ask, nobody just asks "why is there that method?"^^

Comment: thankz for ur response. actually i m trying to learn the functions of all UINavigationControllerDelegate methods.tats y i asked.

Comment: oh, I don't think thats a good way how to learn iOS programming (or programming in general). There are really tons of methods and lots of them are rather specific and you just need to learn them if you need them. A good starting point is CS193P by Stanford University, it's an beginner course which is available through itunesU.